# Button inside ngb-accordion title opens panel by default along with customized function

Tags: angular

I have a button inside ngb-accordion panel for a specific customized functionality, but when I click the button, it is also opening the panel by default.Trying to implement different functionality for panel open and button click.Expecting each should work separately.Here is my code snippet.

```
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" >
    <ngb-panel *ngFor="let item of Array;">
        <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>

            <label>{{item.name}}</label>

            <span style="float: right;">
                <button type="button" name="approve" class="btn btn-success" (click)="customFunction1()" id="approve">Approve</button>
                <button name="reject" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="customFunction2()" id="cancel">Reject</button>
            </span>
        </ng-template>

        <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
            <!-- some content -->
        </ng-template>

    </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>
```

Comment: can you add stackblitz

Comment: Try adding `return false;` after  `(click)="customFunction1()"` like this `(click)="customFunction1(); return false;"`

Comment: Adding (click)="customFunction1(); return false;" results ERROR @AhsanKhurshid

Answer (score 0):

This is what $event.stopPropagation() is for!

```
<button (click)="buttonClicked();$event.stopPropagation()">
```